# Center bootstrap column using offset for small devices only

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment

I am trying to display text alongside an image. I want it to stack only when the device is below 767px wide. Otherwise, I want them to be side by side.
During this stacking, the image is responsive so it takes up and entire row above the text. To avoid this, I tried to limit the size of the column when it is xs. This makes sure the image is within the specified column size.
Now I want to center the image. I tried to use the offset method but it's forcing them to stack at all resolutions.

Here is the code and the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hhbuqqvy/4/)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
        <img
            src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2813/9093733888_79ccacf171_z.jpg"
            alt="pic" class="img-responsive img-circle">
    </div>
    <div
        class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
        <h3>Hello World!</h3>
        <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
            qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

In the above code, as you can see, the image is taking full width on small devices

`<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">`

One way to reduce the size of the image is the reduce the column size. So the above line is changed to

`<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">`

This occupies the left half of the screen. So to center it I added an offset.

`<div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">`

This words fine for xs resolution but the two columns get stacked at higher resolutions (sm, lg) as well.

I'm fairly new to bootstrap, css, html etc. So I might be missing something very obvious here. I couldn't find any relevant solution in this specific case so any help/insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have to reverse the offsetting for each of the other col-classes (although why... I'm not sure):

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-0 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0">
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dpvarcfe/

Comment: Awesome thanks! I would never have figured out that I have to add empty offsets for other classes. I have any idea how that changes things but this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I think I figured out why the extra offset is needed. Since it is mobile first, the offset applied to xs carries over to higher widths i.e sm, md, lg. So when dealing with larger devices, this offset must be removed (by setting it to 0). 
So 
<div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-0 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0">
does not require  col-lg-offset-0 since the offset is already set to 0 for sm which means the offset is applied to larger widths.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. i do find it odd how a few grid-classes do not follow the "cascading up" rule that the core ones do. I guess it's more consistent that this one does though. Nice catch.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I got it right but, maybe this will help you:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">         
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-center">
      <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2813/9093733888_79ccacf171_z.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 text-center">
      <h3>Hello World!</h3>
      <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
        qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Or check the [Demo Here](http://www.bootply.com/KPZ99y7fTy), let me know if this helps you

Comment: The image is still col-xs-12 which means it completely covers the column. I want to reduce this size (maybe col-xs-4) and center it but using col-xs-offset-4 throws the elements off even at higher resolutions.

Comment: `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) { .myImage { max-width: 80%; height: auto; margin: 0 auto; } }` 
I'm not sure what is wrong but try this.

Comment: This works because we are explicitly setting the image width for a particular resolution (overriding bootstrap). But I am still not sure why bootstrap behaves the way it does. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

In Latest stable version of Bootstrap (4.x) none of the above option works because classes for offsets has been changed.

below code works on Bootstrap 4.x

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row m-3">
            <div class="col-10 offset-1 col-sm-10 offset-sm-1 col-md-10 offset-md-1 col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
                <div class="card shadow">
                    <div class="card-header bg-primary">
                        <h2 class="text-white">
                            Register with us
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <span for="txtemail">Email</span>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="txtemail" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <span for="txtpassword">Password</span>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="txtpassword" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <span for="txtmobile">Mobile</span>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="txtmobile" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <span for="sltcountry">Select country</span>
                                <select class="form-control" id="sltcountry" >
                                    <option value="">India</option>
                                    <option value="">US</option>
                                    <option value="">UK</option>
                                    <option value="">Canada</option>
                                </select>    
                            </div>
                            <b>Select gender</b>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="rdogender" value="1" /> Male
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="rdogender" value="0" /> Female
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <b>Select language you can speak and write</b>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="rdogujarati" value="1" /> Gujarati
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="rdohindi" value="2" /> Hindi
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="txtaddress">Address</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="txtaddress" cols="30" rows="3"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group text-right">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-warning">Clear all</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```