# Div not center using class "Col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-2"

Tags: html, css

I have use bootstrap in my application. i want to div center i try to use in div `col-sm-offset`  but not div center .

**I use Class In div** `Col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-2`

My Code Here Below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
.clsborder{
  border:1px solid black;

}

</style>
<body>


  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-2 clsborder">  <h3>Column 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>

    
    
</div>
   </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Note:** i want to Div Center Using `offset` in boostrap

**Js Fiddle Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/c3e1rc4g/)**

Comment: possibly duplicate check this [Center bootstrap column using offset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25480047/center-bootstrap-column-using-offset-for-small-devices-only)

Comment: i also try this.. but i want to col-sm-7 then not center div

Comment: You can't center element using offsets on odd column sizes. Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153234/center-a-column-using-twitter-bootstrap-3. So use `col-sm-8` or `col-sm-6` if you don't want to write custom css.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to center col-md-3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347643/is-it-possible-to-center-col-md-3)

Comment: i also try this.. but i want to col-sm-7 then not center div

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your issue... You want the div centered or the text? :|

Comment: i want to Div Center .

Comment: div center what? The box or the text?

Comment: <div class="col-sm-7"></div> want to center

Comment: The offset you have is right but the content won't center.. Why not try adding `text-align: center;` to your .clsborder class?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found my Answer guides ... Use in **@media query** and build `custom Offset`

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
{
.custom-offset {
    margin-left:21% !important;
}
}
```

**Updated Code below**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
.clsborder{
  border:1px solid black;

}
@media (min-width: 768px)
{
.custom-offset {
    margin-left:21% !important;
}
}


</style>
<body>


  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-2 clsborder">  <h3>Column 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>

    
    
</div>
   </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Js Fiddle Demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/c5amctao/)**

Answer (score 1):

The offset and the column must add up to 12 columns.

Use the formula:

> 12 - col-sm-# / 2

replace hashtag to A number.

If the number has decimals you can not offset it.

8 columns is alright with an offset of 2

If it doesn't work try centering using [css](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Comment: thank for answer .. but your answer not worked .. i mast be use  col-sm-7 then div center using offset

Comment: @Sumitpatel Then it's just not possible with plain bootstrap. There is not col-sm-offset-2.5 in bootstrap. Maybe just add your own class with corresponding margins and / or paddings?